# How to Use Cosine Function as Activation Function in Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow

with tf.variable_scope('layer1-conv1'):

```
    conv1_weights = tf.get_variable("weight",[3,3,3,32],initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
    conv1_biases = tf.get_variable("bias", [32], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input_tensor, conv1_weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    relu1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, conv1_biases))
```

Take the above layer as an example.How should I replace tf.nn.relu with sin(x)? tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, conv1_biases) is a tensor,but the parameter of math.sin() is a number.I hope you can help me. Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you using [tf.math.sin](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/sin)? Documentation says it's elementwise, so should be working.

Comment: It seems to be.like this?   There was no mistake in running.                                                                                    relu1 = tf.math.sin(tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, conv1_biases))

Comment: So using tf.math.sin works?

Comment: I didn't know there was this function before.tf.math.sin，thank you!

Comment: yes! it works,But the effect is unknown.

Answer (score 4):

Use [tf.math.sin](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/sin) as your activation function as it will compute the function elementwise on your tensor.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

the best way I see to do it is to use a custom layer and override only the call method

there is the snake activation in the addons which has sin in it. I am doubtful its efficient tho

maybe look into how the documentation for the exponential function works and just change the type to complex and take the imagery part.

if non of these are fast enough you can use the multiplying element-wise to do the taylor series yourself up to say the 7th power. it should be good enough. if your inputs are very big you may need to implement some kind of modulo.

at the end of the day, sin is probably just some sort of mode and polynomial when the computer runs it so you can use your own unique combination which runs faster on your aplication